# Avermedia Live Gamer Portable Driver

Tags: drivers, games, portable, capture, video-capture-card

I have a video capture card from Avermedia called the Live Gamer Portable. It has a pc free mode which can record 720p60fps, but I wanted it to work in the pc mode, to be able to record 1080p60fps. However, because of oficial driver support being available only to Windows and MAC, I can't use this mode on Ubuntu. I'd like to know if there is a way to make this card work on Ubuntu. I'm not a driver developer, unfortunately :P Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sadly I never heard of it, but the first step I'd do is to spam the company with mails/bugreports/etc of where's the drivers for GNU/Linux. Because if you want them to support, this is exactly how it works. They should be the first to hear the problem. I [see the support link](http://gamerzone.avermedia.com/support/questionnaire) on their site, this is where I'd start. Sry, I wanted to do it too, but they require serial number. **UPD**: ah, [they have a form](http://avertv.avermedia.com/Support/ContactSupport.aspx) to send a ticket. Use it too.